# SQL substring() matching first letter in first- and lastname

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner of the SQL language and wonder a little about how I can match names from my database that has the same first letter in
first- and lastname ?

```
For exemple:
Alex Andersen
Alice Aaronson
Brad Baalman
Brett Baren
Chris Cat
```

And so forth...

My code is:

```
SELECT substring(firstname,1) AS first_letter
AND substring(lastname,1) AS first_letter
FROM kids
ORDER BY firstname
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE` to filter records:

```
SELECT *
FROM kids
WHERE LEFT(firstname, 1) = LEFT(lastname, 1)
ORDER BY firstname;
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM kids
WHERE SUBSTRING(firstname, 1, 1) = SUBSTRING(lastname, 1, 1)
ORDER BY firstname;
```